# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am using [this simple](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) google calendar API javascriptI have not changed the code given in the tutorial except adding my client ID

```
<html>
  <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
      // Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
      // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
      var CLIENT_ID = 'id';

      var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];

      /**
       * Check if current user has authorized this application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES,
            'immediate': true
          }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Handle response from authorization server.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
          loadCalendarApi();
        } else {
          // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
          // clicking authorize button.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
        }
      }

      /**
       * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
       *
       * @param {Event} event Button click event.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
          handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      /**
       * Load Google Calendar client library. List upcoming events
       * once client library is loaded.
       */
      function loadCalendarApi() {
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', listUpcomingEvents);
      }

      /**
       * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
       * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
       * appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listUpcomingEvents() {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 10,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        });

        request.execute(function(resp) {
          var events = resp.items;
          appendPre('Upcoming events:');

          if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
              var event = events[i];
              var when = event.start.dateTime;
              if (!when) {
                when = event.start.date;
              }
              appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
          }

        });
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('output');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="authorize-div" style="display: none">
      <span>Authorize access to Google Calendar API</span>
      <!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
      <button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
        Authorize
      </button>
    </div>
    <pre id="output"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do not understand how to debug google app scripts in a browser. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's not Google Apps Script, it's JavaScript using the Google API (gapi). The error is saying the object being referenced has no `length` property, which most likely means that it is `null`.

Comment: But there are events in the calendar but thats perhaps a console.log might work to debug this

Comment: Did you change something in the code? For me is working fine, even if i have 0 events.

Comment: no I did not change anything except my client ID

Comment: Make sure that you set you up your application.  When you configure your OAuth you need to set the IP and port that you are requesting from.  Hosting from localhost it would be something like `http://localhost:port`